# Horizontal aligning of nvd3 legends

Tags: pie-chart, nvd3.js

I have an nvd3 pie chart like the one given below:

[image: nvd3 pie chart]

As you can see,the legends are automatically aligned vertically. If the numerical values doesnt reach higher numbers the legends would be placed horizontally.

What I need is to place all the legends horizontally,no matter what the values in the numerical fields are.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Extend the chart's width.

Comment: I thought of that solution,but again the UI experience would be flawed. So are there any other options?

Comment: You can try the svg's width but keep the <g> of the chart with the old width. Only the legend would be resized. NVD3 should position the legends horizontally if there is enough space.